# python variables - discord across modules

Tags: python, scope, duplication

I switch program mode by modifying a global value in my main module.

The change is reflected in following function calls originating inside that module, but not when other modules call the same functions.

Is the main module using an old/external/duplicated value when function calls come from the outside?

**main_module.py**

```
import second_module

mode = 1

def print_mode():
  print 'Mode: ' + str(mode)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print_mode()
  mode = 2
  print_mode()
  second_module.problem()
```

**second_module.py**

```
from main_module import print_mode

def problem():
  print_mode()
```

**output**

```
$ python main_module.py
Mode: 1
Mode: 2
Mode: 1
```

Comment: The `global` keyword does nothing there, since it's at module scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you supply at the command line is executed as a module named `__main__` (the `__name__ == '__main__'` condition is is relying on this). Modules are generally only imported once, future imports give another reference to the same module name.

However, this mechanism is based on the module name. `from main_module import print_mode` looks for a module named `main_module`, but there is no such module yet, so the file is loaded again and a separate module called `main_module` is created. This entails executing the code from `main_module.py` again, which again initializes `mode = 1`, but does fails the aforementioned condition and hence doesn't do anything else (such as `mode = 2`).

So you end up with three modules: `__main__`, `second_module`, and `main_module`. `__main__.mode == 2`, but `main_module.mode == 1`, and `second_module.print_mode is main_module.print_mode`, so the `print_mode` call in `second_module` refers to `main_module.mode` which is 2.

The easy way out is not having any logic in `__main__`: Put your entry point in a function `main()` in `main_module.py`, then create a separate script which doesn't do anything other than importing `main_module` and calling `main_module.main()`. Alternatively, don't use globals ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! Will keep `__main__` away from everything else hereafter. 

It would be nice to avoid global variables altogether, but I don't see how one could maintain a program mode/state.

Comment: Another method is to, at the top of the file, add `if __name__ == '__main__': import main_module; main_module.main()`

Comment: Sounds like stopping during the import of `__main__` to import the same module again, and then continue. Would not that still give us three modules?

Comment: @fivecode Yes, you'd get three modules, but avoid the problem of having any application state duplicated. This holds for all the approaches mentioned here.